Risks around eSIM providers with cheap plans
I often find that some of eSIM providers are able to offer very cheap plans as compared to actual mobile companies which own the network. For example Nomad/Lyca provide very cheap plans which make them quite attractive options for eSIMs.
But it seems counterintuitive that they are able to offer cheap plan than actual network owner, so it makes me wonder if there is any catch? Are there any risks when we go for cheap eSIM plan providers?

The fact that they use e-SIMs and the fact they are a virtual mobile network operator (MVNO) are two different, unrelated things. MVNOs can offer physical SIMs and actual network operators can offer e-SIMs.

It's mostly a marketing and price discrimination issue. In France for example, each of the main network operators have a discount brand offering much lower prices (Sosh for Orange, RED by SFR for SFR, and B&You for Bouygues Telecom). To avoid cannibalizing revenue from their premium brands, the discount brands initially used separate sales channels, fewer perks, and more limited customer service (mainly Internet, no physical shops) but even these differences seem to have faded over time.
You can also see a similar dynamic with roaming charges. Operators are able to offer reasonably cheap data packages but still charge outrageous rates if you don't buy a package in advance. Network operators are not setting their rates based strictly on costs and wholesale prices are much lower. In some cases, regulation also caps wholesale prices (e.g. international roaming in the EU).
The reason why all that is possible is that marginal costs for additional traffic is actually very low. Once you have invested a lot of capital into the network, any marginal income is beneficial and you might find it profitable to resell some capacity at a much cheaper price, at least if you can preserve the revenue from your existing customers (and reselling through third parties can be helpful there: outside the UK, Lyca is a niche brand, not really a threat to existing operators).
Note that none of this really is about eSIMs. On a technical level, Lyca Mobile is a MVNO (Mobile virtual network operator). MVNOs predate eSIMs and Lyca still offers prepaid plans with regular SIMs. Conversely, it's possible to get an eSIM for a traditional plan from a network operator. Sometimes it is even sold as a premium service with an extra charge (e.g. to put in a smartwatch or tablet).
As far as quality of service goes, there are nuances and different kinds of MVNOs but in general they use the same infrastructure and the technology is mature. I have used both travel data eSIMs abroad and a domestic full-service MVNO with a regular SIM and I have always found them good enough for my use (which doesn't include video streaming). It is however possible for the network operators to deprioritize traffic from these virtual networks and others have reported performance issues.
Another small performance hit comes from routing the data through the operator's home country. When roaming in another country, latency will be a bit higher compared to a local provider. That's true whether your provider is a legacy network operator in another country, a full-service MVNO, or a travel-oriented data-only MVNO but the latter don't always clearly advertise where they are based (which is why you might notice Google serving you some random local version you didn't expect).
Beyond that, the main differences will be found in additional services (e.g. streaming, games), how you can get customer support, and perhaps in the terms and conditions (e.g. how hard it is to actually unsubscribe) but even there I wouldn't say MVNOs are universally worse than network operators.

There are most definitely quality of service differences in the US. I have a very cheap MVNO provider for a second number and they cap their throughput at 3 Mbps. Streaming bitrate limits also vary, even within postpaid plans. QoS prioritization is comprehensively deployed; MVNOs are almost always deprioritized (couple offer paid limited prioritzation), and even cheaper postpaid plans do this as well. Overall: calling, texting no differences. Streaming, big difference. Everything else is fine until you hit an overloaded cell site (often residential, rural areas).

@user71659 Thanks for the comment, I edited the answer accordingly.

@DannyBeckett Thanks for the info, I reworded the answer a little bit.

@user71659 curious, have you tried using a VPN? OpenVPN over port 443 as a basic solution, ShadowSocks as a more advanced solution to bypass the limits.

+1 to the answer, the only thing missing is the latency issue. eSIMs from travel operators usually route their traffic via the Baltics, UK or Hong Kong, so you often end up with an extra 50-250ms latency. Not necessarily a dealbreaker but can be annoying.

@JonathanReez I added a paragraph on that, thanks. Made me realize that we have never really been clear on what we were comparing. Travel-oriented eSIM vs. local provider or travel oriented eSIM vs. roaming package from a network operator in your home country. With the latter, latency will also increase and price is almost certainly higher.

@JonathanReez Bitrate cap and LTE layer-2 prioritization (QCI) isn't application dependent, so a VPN won't matter.


it seems counterintuitive that they are able to offer cheap plan than actual network owner

Your intuition is wrong. Building and maintaining a network has its own costs, which must be offset on the rates charged to customers in order to be covered. Those costs are not incurred by e-sim providers.
The risks that you might have with cheap providers, but not only with them, are:

you might get no coverage or very poor coverage in some areas,
interacting with their customer service can be a nerve wracking experience, especially if their service number is not free,
they might have hidden or very high fees for particular use cases (make sure to read the fine prints), e.g. exceeding the data usage or calling certain numbers.


That's not exactly how the economics work. Mobile virtual network operators (whether they offer eSIMs or not) do pay the network operators for the traffic they generate and if it was not profitable for the operators, they wouldn't resell access and would lobby hard to change any regulation that forces them to.

Sure, but the mainstream operators are essentially capitalizing on free capacity of their network - that is, they need to pay fixed costs of operating it in any case, so MVNO revenue is free money**. If they don't resell the network capacity, they're still stuck with fixed costs of maintaining the networks, so it's a pure win for them to allow others to use the infrastructure cheaply (while making sure they're lower priority than their own subscribers).
This calculation would of course significantly change if MVNO subscriber numbers would beat operators native subscriber numbers.

In theory major networks offer improved customer service (including physical stores and anti-fraud departments), but they don't always provide the best service in reality (in the UK Vodafone scores much worse than Giff Gaff or Tesco Mobile). Many people prefer to buy from a well-known name, no matter how bad it is, and are too lazy/confused to switch. What traditional networks do seem to offer is a bizarre range of discounts and freebies. And some networks run their own MVNOs, so the MVNOs operate as bargain/discount brands offering a basic service at a low cost.

@Mavrik on the other hand there's generally no penalty in over selling the capacity, so during peak hours and/or in congested areas it's entirely possible for MVNO traffic to be slower (or not work at all) compared to the carrier's retail customers.

Yes, absolutely. Also when base stations run out of slots, the MVNO users are the first to be degraded down - e.g. from 5G to 4G or even from 4G to no data/signal at all. Or, as you say, if a base station runs out of backbone bandwidth or channels, the subscribers of the owners will get priority to get their data through - and MVNO users will just not get any data transfer. That's what I meant by "lower priority".

The main risk with these travel-focused eSIM resellers like Nomad is that the connectivity you get with these travel-focused eSIM providers is extremely unpredictable, and I would not recommend having it as your sole source of connectivity. Getting a refund for the defective service is also difficult though possible if you have enough patience.
The reason the prices are so cheap is that they're buying bottom-of-the-barrel capacity and you should consider yourself lucky if you manage to get usable speeds consistently.
Furthermore, the data sessions can be terminated far away from your physical location, adding not only latency but giving you a foreign IP address. This may trip fraud detection or geo-blocking systems/etc if you're trying to access/pay for things locally.
I recommend you avoid wasting your time with these "travel" eSIM providers and pick up a prepaid/pay-as-you-go (e?)SIM from a local provider in your destination country. It will most likely be even cheaper, the speeds will be much better and actually usable, you will get a local IP address indistinguishable from a local, and as a bonus you get an actual local phone number which might come in handy if some service requires SMS verification/etc.

Are you using these travel-focused eSIM often?

Depends on your definition of 'usable speed'. I have a EU subscription, and last month I went on a road trip around Lake Michigan and decided to try a free (read: paid by watching ads) eSIM option based in the Netherlands. Yes, I wouldn't have been able to use Netflix or FaceTime, but I consider that a feature. You can also do that when you're back on WiFi, just like downloading offline maps, which IMHO is essential travel preparation :)

@Relaxed used them twice, different countries, different carriers. In both cases the product was not fit for purpose - 100ms latency and single-digit megabits per second in an area where the local carrier's own SIM pulls hundreds of mbps. Conclusion: a scam and waste of time.

@Glorfindel when it comes to travel a reasonable situation you might find yourself in is to have to download the local transport/taxi company app on short notice. With the size of those apps today, downloading one on a connection that's not capable of FaceTime or Netflix is going to take ~30 mins. That's a potentially huge liability that can trivially be mitigated by picking up a local SIM.

So you have two bad experiences? And you took the time to get a local SIM and compare in both cases?

@Relaxed one was in my home country, so I already had a local one to compare to. The second one was in a foreign country and I ended up having to pick up a prepaid SIM just to be able to have usable connectivity. Am I saying it's impossible to have a good experience with these? No, I'm sure you can get lucky and it'll work just fine. But why would you want to even risk being stranded in a foreign country without connectivity (no access to maps/translate/ordering transport/etc) when you can just pick up any local prepaid SIM?

“Just” is doing a lot of work in your last sentence. In actual fact, getting a data eSIM on a marketplace is almost certainly cheaper and way easier than a local SIM, for starters. I get data when the plane is still taxiing... I am asking about the basis for your answer because it seems pretty absolute (“scam”, “not fit for purpose”, “unusable”). That hasn't been my experience at all and, since I am not as disappointed as you are, I have actually been using travel SIMs in several countries and more than twice ;)

Incidentally, I have also had pretty good experience at home with a MVNO that's not travel-oriented and I have been pushing it way beyond what I would consider a reasonable and perfectly usable travel experience (e.g. used it as an access point for a couple of laptops doing calls through VPNs).

@Relaxed I'm glad it works for you, and I'd appreciate if you could share which provider you used (in my case it was Nomad in the UK and Spain, and both were unsatisfactory). In an era where any cheap prepaid SIM gives you triple-digits speeds, a provider which provides single-digits mbps is a scam, sorry, even more so if they list 4G/5G connectivity as a selling point (implying fast speeds).

Honestly, at $3 to $5 a pop (going price for something like 3GB over 7 days), even if everything you wrote is true, I still don't see any serious reason not to get a data eSIM. It is spares me sourcing a local solution, fiddling with physical SIMs or buying a package from my main operator even half of the time, I am still winning.

@Relaxed if you only need the packages for a few days/few GBs then I guess it works well (and you're losing pocket change if it doesn't). I find that beyond a few dozen gigabytes or about 15 days, the math doesn't work out and a local prepaid becomes cheaper, so even from a purely financial perspective it only makes sense in limited cases.

Provider varies, I believe the last one I used was called Sparks. The local MVNO I alluded to is RED by SFR in France. I don't use any of these in the EU obviously, as that's covered under my regular plan.

Maybe Sparks is using a different host carrier under the hood, whose roaming arrangements & peering links with the visited carriers aren't as overloaded as Nomad's. And yeah when it comes to domestic MVNOs it's a whole different issue and shouldn't even come in this discussion. MVNOs may be deprioritized if a given area is over capacity, but that's a rare occurrence and not worth worrying about. Travel eSIM providers on the other hand knowingly sell lower-priority capacity, sometimes so low priority that it's not usable.

@AndréBorie That sounds right but needing more than 5 to 10 GB a month is going beyond typical travel use for me (only really use that when I am working remotely personally) and the super-cheap price is part of the appeal.

@AndréBorie again, sounds like essential travel preparation :) During my previous trip (April 2023), I bought a physical SIM card for $50, and had a weak signal on most of the Appalachian Trail in Massachusetts. I wouldn't have wanted to download a 30MB app there either. Of course, it's a matter of how much risk you want to take; I remember checking out the options for satellite internet during a three week climb to Mt. Aconcagua.

"In an era where any cheap prepaid SIM gives you triple-digits speeds" well, in my country, standard prepaid SIM gives 1-digit Mbit (and I never had any issue with daily activity with that speed), so... your mileage may vary :)

-1 because this does not match my experience with travel SIMs at all. The latency part is true and I’d keep it in your answer but the rest is not in my experience.
